# Pass value emitted by Observable to different object while combining it

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I want to pass every emitted value in 3 objects and for one object we can basically do as usual:

```
Observable.just(KV("1", "Alex"), KV("2", "LeBron"), KV("3", "Kobe"), KV("1", "Kevin"))
.flatMapCompletable(keyValue -> doSth(keyValue))
```

But for others I'd like to groupBy(KV::getKey) and then collect (for example, concat values).

```
Observable.just(KV("1", "Alex"), KV("2", "LeBron"), KV("3", "Kobe"), KV("1", "Kevin"))
.groupBy(KV::getKey)
.collect(Result::new, (acc, keyVal) -> acc.add(keyVal.getVal()))
.flatMapCompletable(result -> writeResultSomeWhere());
```

How can I do this in 1 chain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could `publish` the main source:

```
Observable.just(KV("1", "Alex"), KV("2", "LeBron"), KV("3", "Kobe"), KV("1", "Kevin"))
.publish(o -> Completable.merge(
    o.flatMapCompletable(keyValue -> doSth(keyValue)),
    o.groupBy(KV::getKey)
       .collect(Result::new, (acc, keyVal) -> acc.add(keyVal.getVal()))
       .flatMapCompletable(result -> writeResultSomeWhere())
));
```